# RAILS: Stop Caching for Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

We are load testing an application. I just want to check how it behaves if it hits database every time a request is made. I want to stop all type of caching temporarily. Is there a to do this?

Thanks,

Imran

Answer (score 0):

In development mode by default no caching performed. You can adjust caching in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`

E.g., there're following values in the production config by default

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true
```